# Entity Framework: Split table into multiple tables

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following table [PaymentComponent] created using following EF code first approach (TPH inheritance). It works fine. I need to change the database design – need to store GiftCouponPayments in GiftCouponPayment table and ClubCardPayments in ClubCardPayment table. What change need to be done in C# code to get the required database structure?

[image]

**CODE**

```
public abstract class PaymentComponent
{
    public int PaymentComponentID { get; set; }
    public int MyValue { get; set; }
    public string MyType { get; set; }
    public abstract int GetEffectiveValue();
}


public partial class GiftCouponPayment : PaymentComponent
{

    public override int GetEffectiveValue()
    {
        if (MyValue < 2000)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return MyValue;
    }

}


public partial class ClubCardPayment : PaymentComponent
{
    public override int GetEffectiveValue()
    {
        return MyValue;
    }
}

public partial class Payment
{
    public int PaymentID { get; set; }
    public List<PaymentComponent> PaymentComponents { get; set; }
    public DateTime PayedTime { get; set; }

}



//System.Data.Entity.DbContext is from EntityFramework.dll
public class NerdDinners : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{

    public NerdDinners(string connString): base(connString)
    { 

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelbuilder)
    {
        modelbuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }


    public DbSet<GiftCouponPayment> GiftCouponPayments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClubCardPayment> ClubCardPayments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Payment> Payments { get; set; }

}
```

**CLIENT**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string connectionstring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=NerdDinners;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

    using (var db = new NerdDinners(connectionstring))
    {
        GiftCouponPayment giftCouponPayment = new GiftCouponPayment();
        giftCouponPayment.MyValue=250;
        giftCouponPayment.MyType = "GiftCouponPayment";

        ClubCardPayment clubCardPayment = new ClubCardPayment();
        clubCardPayment.MyValue = 5000;
        clubCardPayment.MyType = "ClubCardPayment";

        List<PaymentComponent> comps = new List<PaymentComponent>();
        comps.Add(giftCouponPayment);
        comps.Add(clubCardPayment);

        var payment = new Payment { PaymentComponents = comps, PayedTime=DateTime.Now };
        db.Payments.Add(payment);

        int recordsAffected = db.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

**REFERENCE**:

1. [How do I get Entity Framework 4.3 Code First to map a subclass using Table Per Type (TPT)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511021/how-do-i-get-entity-framework-4-3-code-first-to-map-a-subclass-using-table-per-t)
2. http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/24/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-4-table-splitting.aspx
3. http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-entity-splitting/
4. Entity Framework Mapping Scenarios - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716779.aspx
5. http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/03/06/entity-splitting-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: @LadislavMrnka What do you suggest about the following EF Table Splitting – The Opposite of Entity Splitting - http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/ef-table-splitting-ndash-the-opposite-of-entity-splitting/ ?

Comment: Table splitting will not help you in scenario where you want to use derived entity types.

Answer (score 1):

In your Context class in OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<GiftCouponPayment>()
                .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.MapInheritedProperties();
                    m.ToTable("GiftCouponPayment");
                });

modelBuilder.Entity<ClubCardPayment>()
                .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.MapInheritedProperties();
                    m.ToTable("ClubCardPayment");
                });
```

Comment: With this. I am getting exception - "AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges." Any thoughts?

Comment: [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2010/10/06/self-tracking-entities-applychanges-and-duplicate-entities.aspx) may help.