# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker in EF data access layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, architecture, data-layer

I have seen plenty of questions regarding the same topic, but never found solution as yet. The code that is bringing me problems is:

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(FullOrderViewModel fullOrder)
    {
        //Get all order items
        List<OrderItem> orderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
        foreach (var oi in fullOrder.Order)
        {
            var color = _colorRepo.Find(oi.ColorId);
            var item = new OrderItem
            {
                Quantity = oi.Quantity,
                Color = color
            };
            orderItems.Add(item);
        }

        //Get customer id
        var customer = await _adminRepo.GetCustomerByUserName(fullOrder.Customer.UserName);

        var billAddress = _addressRepo.All.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AddressLine == fullOrder.BillingAddress.AddressLine && x.PostalCode == fullOrder.BillingAddress.PostalCode);
        var deliveryAddress = _addressRepo.All.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AddressLine == fullOrder.DeliveryAddress.AddressLine && x.PostalCode == fullOrder.DeliveryAddress.PostalCode);

        //CASE : sample order
        if (fullOrder.OrderType == OrderType.Sample)
        {
            var order = new SampleOrder {
                Type = OrderType.Sample,
                Status = "Unauthorized",
                Origin = Origin.Online,
                OrderItems = orderItems,
                CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                CustomerId = customer.Id,
                BillAddressId = billAddress.AddressId,
                DeliveryAddressId = deliveryAddress.AddressId
            };
            try
            {
                _sampleOrderRepo.InserGraph(order);
                _unitOfWork.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return InternalServerError(e);
            }
```

The way I get my repositories is via dependency injection in the OrderController constructor, so in a standard way as I believe. Each of my repos is build in this way:

```
public class SampleOrderRepository : EntityRepository<SampleOrder, IPhoeniceUnitOfWork<PhoeniceContext>>, ISampleOrderRepository
{
    public SampleOrderRepository(IPhoeniceUnitOfWork<PhoeniceContext> unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork)
    {
    }

    protected override IDbSet<SampleOrder> List(IPhoeniceUnitOfWork<PhoeniceContext> unitOfWork)
    {
        return unitOfWork.Context.SampleOrders;
    }

    protected override Expression<Func<SampleOrder, bool>> FindInt(int id)
    {
        return x => x.OrderId == id;
    }
}
```

Where I override methods from general entity repository:

```
public abstract class EntityRepository<T, TContext> : IEntityRepository<T> 
    where T : class, IObjectWithState
    where TContext : IUnitOfWork<EntityContext>
{
    protected readonly TContext _unitOfWork;

    protected EntityRepository(TContext unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    protected virtual IDbSet<T> List(TContext unitOfWork)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("List operation not implemented!");
    }

    protected virtual Expression<Func<T, bool>> FindInt(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Finding entity with an int is not implemented!");
    }

    protected virtual Expression<Func<T, bool>> FindString(string id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Finding entity with an int is not implemented!");
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> All { get { return List(_unitOfWork); } }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        return includeProperties.Aggregate(All, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
    }

    public virtual T Find(int id)
    {
        return All.FirstOrDefault(FindInt(id));
    }

    public virtual T FindByString(string id)
    {
        return All.FirstOrDefault(FindString(id));
    }

    public virtual void InserGraph(T entity)
    {
        List(_unitOfWork).Add(entity);
    }

    public void InsertOrUpdate(T entity)
    {
        if (entity.ObjectState == State.Added) // New entity
        {
            _unitOfWork.Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else        // Existing entity
        {
            _unitOfWork.Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _unitOfWork.Context.ApplyStateChanges();
        }
    }

    public virtual void Delete(int id)
    {
        var entity = Find(id);
        List(_unitOfWork).Remove(entity);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

Finally this is my UnitOfWork item:

```
public class PhoeniceUnitOfWork : IPhoeniceUnitOfWork<PhoeniceContext>
{
    private readonly PhoeniceContext _context;

    public PhoeniceUnitOfWork() : base()
    {
        _context = new PhoeniceContext();
    }

    //Left for testing purposes
    public PhoeniceUnitOfWork(PhoeniceContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public int Save()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    public IAddressRepository AddressRepository
    {
        get { return new AddressRepository(this); }
    }

    public IColorRepository ColorRepository
    {
        get { return new ColorRepository(this); }
    }

    public IHideOrderRepository HideOrderReposiotory
    {
        get { return new HideOrderRepository(this); }
    }

    public ISampleOrderRepository SampleOrderRepository
    {
        get { return new SampleOrderRepository(this); }
    }

    public ITaxonomyRepository TaxonomyRepository
    {
        get { return new TaxonomyRepository(this); }
    }

    PhoeniceContext IUnitOfWork<PhoeniceContext>.Context
    {
        get { return _context; }
    }
}
```

and context that I'm using

```
public class PhoeniceContext : EntityContext
{
    // You can add custom code to this file. Changes will not be overwritten.
    // 
    // If you want Entity Framework to drop and regenerate your database
    // automatically whenever you change your model schema, add the following
    // code to the Application_Start method in your Global.asax file.
    // Note: this will destroy and re-create your database with every model change.
    // 
    // System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Phoenice.EntityFramework.Models.PhoeniceContext>());

    public PhoeniceContext()
        : base("Phoenice")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<PhoeniceContext>(new DropCreateIfChangeInitializer());
        //Database.SetInitializer<PhoeniceContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways());
    }

    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SampleOrder> SampleOrders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<HideOrder> HideOrders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Color> Colors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Taxonomy> Taxonomies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //There is OnModelCreating already overwritten in IdentityDbContext 
        //with all details required for ASP.NET identity
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        //solution for this mapping: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632951/primary-key-violation-inheritance-using-ef-code-first
        modelBuilder.Entity<SampleOrder>()
            .HasKey(x => x.OrderId)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                //Requires EF 6.1
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
                m.ToTable("SampleOrders");
            })
            .Property(x => x.OrderId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        modelBuilder.Entity<HideOrder>().Map(m =>
        {
            //Requires EF 6.1
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("HideOrders");
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<HideOrder>().HasKey(x => x.OrderId);
    }
}
```

I know that it's a lot of code that I am showing, but hope these are all of the building blocks for data access layer. For some reason when I call InsertGraph method on SampleOrders I get "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker" exception. I looked through this code dozens of times, and cannot get why does it throw this error message

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure of my answer, but i will suggest you the following :

my version of entity Framework is a bit different so i'm not sure you'll have all required functionnality. When you do this

`List<OrderItem> orderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
        foreach (var oi in fullOrder.Order)
        {
            var color = _colorRepo.Find(oi.ColorId);
            var item = new OrderItem
            {
                Quantity = oi.Quantity,
                Color = color
            };
            orderItems.Add(item);
        }`

I think you should first detach all your oi objects then the code should be something like

```
List<OrderItem> orderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
    foreach (var oi in fullOrder.Order)
    {
        //detach oi
         //attach oi
        var color = _colorRepo.Find(oi.ColorId);
        var item = new OrderItem
        {
            Quantity = oi.Quantity,
            Color = color
        };
        orderItems.Add(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The items in your orderItems contains color. Which is returned by:

```
_colorRepo.Find(oi.ColorId);
```

The colorRepo holds the entities of color.

The order in the next line is used by another repo, but in 'order' there are colors from the previous repo.

```
   _sampleOrderRepo.InserGraph(order);
```

Two repo's are holding the same entity object which causes this exception.

To avoid this problem you can two things:

Create a new object of Color every time you use _colorRepo.Find():

```
var color = new Color()
{
     id = oi.ColorId

}
```

or use only one repo by moving the functionality to the services